# iPhone Bluetooth LE background scan proper approach

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to scan for and connect to Bluetooth LE devices in the background. It's working great, except for the fact that the app will only discover devices if the screen is turned on. For testing, I send a push notification that triggers the app to scan and connect to bluetooth devices. If I lock the device, so the screen is off, I get no devices discovered. If I turn the screen on, even without unlocking the phone, then all works as expected. Does anyone know how to get Bluetooth LE scans to work while the screen is off?

## EDIT:

I thought I'd clarify, when I setup my CBCentralManger, this is the code that I use:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey, nil];
self.manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:options];
```

then when I start my scan in the background, this is the code I call:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:true] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kFilterUUID]];
[self.manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:options];
```

I tried setting up a dispatch_queue_t for the CBCentralManager, but when I created one like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t centralQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.novatek.mycentral", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

My scans stopped working at all, even not in the background. Is a custom queue necessary for what I'm trying to do? If so, what's the proper way to set one up?

Comment: How long did you wait?  Scanning in the background can take 60 times longer, maybe more.  Was the peripheral previously discovered by the app?  If so the OS me might be ignoring duplicate discoveries.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? My app can detect new peripherals in the foreground and background. But NOT when the phone is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled the proper background mode in the target capabilities page. Go to the Capabilities tab for your target and switch "Background Modes" to ON, the check "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories".

Comment: Already had that checked. Do you have working apps that initiate bluetooth scans/connections while the screen is off?

Answer (score 0):

While you're in the background CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey is ignored.  So you'll only receive one didDiscoverPeripheral once you're in the background, by design.

There are more details on [Core Bluetooth Background Processing for iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1).  See the section "The bluetooth-central Background Execution Mode" for the requirements and limitations of background scanning.

This bullet point that directly applies to your issue -

> The CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey scan option key is
>   ignored, and multiple discoveries of an advertising peripheral are
>   coalesced into a single discovery event.